# south.exceptions.NoMigration – djcelery

Tags: python, django

I just added a many-to-many relationship to my model and generated the new migration file:

`py manage.py schemamigration myapp --auto`

Then tried running the migration:

`py manage.py migrate myapp`

It did not complete successfully, raising a `south.exceptions.NoMigrations` exception:

```
south.exceptions.NoMigrations: Application '<module 'djcelery' from 'C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\djcelery\__init__.pyc'>' has no migrations.
```

No more information is given, and I cannot figure out what might be wrong. Has anybody experienced this issue before?

I am using Python 2.7 and Django 1.4.22.

Comment: before this new migration everything was working fine?

Comment: Do you mean if I got any errors in the app? I did not.

Comment: I am just thinking if it can be something simple like python manage.py makemigrations which create migrations for djcelery? Also I think that djcelery is not recommended anymore so probably you can remove it at all?

Comment: I tried reinstalling `requirements.txt`, then solved some other issues and that did it. Weird.

Comment: yes,but at least solved the bug!