# Django: cannot import name migrations

Tags: python, django, django-1.4

I had an issue I just posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41611734/south-exceptions-nomigration-djcelery). I saw an answer to a similar question which said uninstalling and installing `requirements.txt` would help because the root of the issue was a bad dependency chain.

So I did that and now, of course, I ran into a new issue.

When running the migrations, I am getting the following error:

```
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\genericm2m\migrations\0001_initial.py", line 5, in <module>
    from django.db import migrations, models
ImportError: cannot import name migrations
```

According to another answer, this is caused because I am using the migrations module, which my Django version (1.4) doesn't support yet.

It seems like the `django-generic-m2m` module (version 0.3.1) is using migrations. I don't understand why this issue is happening now, as I have always used the same `requirements.txt` file and I never had this problem.

I used to have similar problems with dependencies using migrations while my Django couldn't handle them. But these deps also had a `south_migrations` folder, so just renaming it to `migrations` and getting rid of the actual `migrations` folder would do the trick. However, I don't see any `south_migrations` directory in the `generic2m2` installation dir.

Has anybody had this issue before?

Comment: Why are you using 1.4, which is several years old and completely unsupported?

Comment: Because it is not up to me to choose it.

Comment: Unless you pin your requirements (e.g. `genericm2m==0.3.0` or `genericm2m<0.3.1`), installing with a requirements file may use newer versions that break your application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The app does not have South migrations, and as far as I can find, it never had them. It probably used to rely on 'syncdb' to create the database tables.

Newer Django doesn't have syncdb, so migrations to create the tables were added.

If you are used to renaming migrations directories anyway, then you could probably just remove the migrations/ directory, but you should really upgrade to a supported version.

Also, your old fix of renaming south_migrations to migrations wasn't the intended use: if you use Django-South 1.0 (the last version of django-south ever), it will detect when a south_migrations directory is present and use it instead of the migrations directory.

So you should also update South to 1.0, and then *adding* an empty south_migrations/ directory may also work (I don't know).

Comment: Yeah I deleted the migrations folder and that did it.